# Debian Partitions - Which partition is the Database in?

Tags: linux, debian, partitioning

We have a Debain server, and we have our database on this server. I would like to see which partition the database resides in. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Which database are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is default running of `/var/lib/mysql`. To find which partition, you could easily run

```
df /var/lib/mysql
```

from your shell. If it's not there you will get an error and we will have to search a little more. but lets start with a lazy long shot.

Comment: I've just tried this on another server that i need to work on. And the results shows the below output: df: '/var/lib/mysql': No such file or directory and df: no file systems processed. I need to create a database on this server...

Comment: Please add to your initial post, it's a little hard to head in these small comment boxes.

Comment: Ah, there. you sill have to locate your `my.cnf` file. It's often called `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. in there locate the `datadir` key

Comment: datadir = /var/lib/mysql. I am trying to create a new database on this server. This is something i haven't done before. Can i get some help with that?

Comment: I think you should make a new post on that one. it sounds like your mysql installation on the server is a little broken. Also, it's hardly a programming problem, perhaps over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ it would be a better fit